# SQL injections in ADOdb and general website security

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection, adodb

I have done pretty much reading and still don't understand 100% how some of the SQL injections happen!

I'd like to see, from those who know, concrete examples of SQL injection based on my example, so it could be replicated, tested and fixed. I have tried to SQL inject my code and couldn't, so I'd like someone to prove me otherwise!

1.Am I right that SQL injection can happen ONLY with POST or GET methods, meaning that on the website it should be the post form, e.g. 'signup or search' or query like 'search.php?tags=love'?

Saying that is this possible to inject the following code that has POST method?

```
$name     = trim($_POST['username']);
$mail     = trim($_POST['email']);
$password = trim($_POST['password ']);

   if ($errors == "false") {
    $sql = 
        "INSERT INTO 
           clients 
         SET 
           name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "',
           mail='" . mysql_real_escape_string($mail) . "', 
           password='" . mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($password)) . "'";
           $connection->execute($sql);
        
    }
```

2.The other one has GET method: `rate.php?like&videoID=250&userID=30`

```
$sql = 
    "SELECT 
        videoID 
     FROM 
        likes 
     WHERE 
        videoID = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($videoID). "' AND UID = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($userID). "' LIMIT 1";
        $connection->execute($sql);
```

Please help those that feel free with the subject but use the concrete examples.

Thanks in advance,

Ilia

Comment: "Am I right that SQL injection can happen ONLY with POST or GET methods?" No. You can inject SQL in cookies too.

Comment: Interesting, but it implies affecting to the global variable? Is this really possible? Could you be kind provide an example, please?

Comment: Yes. A perfect example is a language cookie. `$_COOKIE['lng'] = 'en-en'`. I can change my cookie to `en'; SELECT SLEEP(20);`. Then while querying the language in database, the query will get stuck for a while.

Comment: Indeed great example! So the cookie must also be escaped when it's sent to db? I use this, is this good enough: `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['current_session']['username']);`

Comment: Yes. As phihag answered, don't try to guess if it's user input or not. Even if today you use a static value, next week you might replace the static value with a user input, and forget about it. So use phihag's advice, and escape everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL injection attacks happen when *user input* is improperly encoded. Typically, the user input is some data the user sends with her query, i.e. values in the `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_REQUEST`, or `$_SERVER` arrays. However, user input can also come from a variety of other sources, like sockets, remote websites, files, etc.. Therefore, you should really **treat everything but constants** (like `'foobar'`) **as user input**.

In the code you posted, [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is used to encode(=escape) user inputs. The code is therefore correct, i.e. does not allow any SQL injection attacks.

Note that it's very easy to forget the call to `mysql_real_escape_string` - and one time is enough for a skilled attacker! Therefore, you may want to use the modern [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of adodb.

Comment: Nice to hear this! Thank you very much for answering! :)

Comment: "and one time is enough for a skilled attacker"! hmm .. but the attacker doesn't see the source code?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev They don't see the code. But don't worry, they will try every form, cookie (session cookie as well), ajax, basically anything that could be used to inject SQL.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev The attacker doesn't know the php code, but by looking at the forms and code, he knows the names of the GET/POST parameters. And he can just [automatically try all of them](http://maestro-sec.com/blogs/2008/10/top-15-sql-injection-scanner/).

Comment: Is there a way to monitor all of this without writing any special codes for creating logs? Is there a known way of doing this?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Sorry, but I don't exactly know what you mean by `all of this`, but it seems like you want an [IDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_Detection_System).

Comment: @phihag This is exactly what I wanted to ask! I will read and keep learning! Many thanks again! ;)

Comment: In response to phihag's statement "Therefore, you may want to use the modern PDO with prepared statements instead of adodb.", I'd like to point out that ADOdb is perfectly capable of executing parameterized queries, e.g. $sql = 'insert into table (col1,col2) values ('.$DB->Param('a').','.$DB->Param('b').')'; $stmt = $DB->Prepare($sql); $stmt = $DB->Execute($stmt,array('one','two'));

Answer (score 2):

I've been investigating thoroughly on this subject recently and would like to share with others quite interesting material, thus, making my question more complete and instructive for everyone.

- [Preventing SQL Injection with PHP by John Nebel](http://www.digifuzz.net/archives/2007/07/preventing-sql-injection-with-php/)
- [Security Corner - SQL Injection by Chris Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/articles/sql-injection)
- [The Unexpected SQL Injection by Alexander Andonov](http://webappsec.org/projects/articles/091007.txt)
- [Mysql_real_escape_string() versus Prepared Statements by Ilia Alshanetsky](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html)
- [SQL Injection Attack and Defense by Sagar Joshi](http://www.packetsource.com/article/sql-injection/40060/sql-injection-attack-and-defense)
- [SQL Injection Attacks by Prof. Jim Whitehead](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps183/Spring06/lectures/SQL%20Injection%20Attacks.pdf)
- [addslashes() vs mysql_real_escape_string() by Chris Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string)
- [What's a SQL Injection Bug by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/11/01.html)
- [MySQL - SQL injection prevention](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)
- [SQL Injection Walkthrough](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5DP0N1P76E.html)
- [SQL Injection Cheat Sheet](http://ferruh.mavituna.com/sql-injection-cheatsheet-oku/#about)
- [Prepared Statements in PHP and MySQLi](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/)

---

### **From YouTube**

- [SQL Injection Myths & Fallacies: Best practices of defense by Bill Karwin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4dJ7hdA8fs)
- [PHP Tutorials: Security - SQL Injection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bORZlmyDw0s&feature=fvst)
- [How to SQL Inject with SQLMAP on Backtrack5 RC1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-F1nBasky6E&feature=related)

---

### **From Wikipedia**

- [Wikipedia - SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- [Wikipedia - SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)

---

### **From OWASP**

- [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)
- [Guide to SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_SQL_Injection)
- [OWASP - Avoiding SQL Injection](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Avoiding_SQL_Injection#WARNING:_Escaping_table_names)
- [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
- [Testing for SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_%28OWASP-DV-005%29)

---

### **From PHP Manual**

- [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)
- [PDO class - Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)
- [MySQL Improved Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

---

### **From Microsoft and Oracle**

- [What's the Right Way to Prevent SQL Injection in PHP Scripts by Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/04/what_2700_s-the-right-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-php-scripts_3f00_.aspx)
- [Stop SQL Injection Attacks Before They Stop You by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx)
- [Defending Against SQL Injection Attacks by Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/oll/tutorials/SQLInjection/index.htm)

---

### **Stack Overflow**

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)
- [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks
- [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection/601524#601524)
- [SQL injection on INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681583/sql-injection-on-insert)
- [How do I protect this function from SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862036/how-do-i-protect-this-function-from-sql-injection/1862178#1862178)
- [Are Parameters really enough to prevent Sql injections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306668/are-parameters-really-enough-to-prevent-sql-injections/306818#306818)
- [Is SQL injection a risk today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683843/is-sql-injection-a-risk-today/1684292#1684292)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936254/sql-injection
- [SQL Injection ethical hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936646/sql-injection-ethical-hacking)
- [Does this code prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800013/does-this-code-prevent-sql-injection?lq=1)

---

### **SQL injection scanner**

- [Top 15 SQL injection scanner](http://maestro-sec.com/blogs/2008/10/top-15-sql-injection-scanner/)
- [Netsparker Community Edition, Free SQL Injection Scanner & XSS Scanner](http://www.mavitunasecurity.com/communityedition/)