# PHP mysql insert date format

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

I'm using jQuery datepicker
the format of the datepicker is this `08/25/2012`

I have errors when inserting to my database it inserts only 0000-00-00 00 00 00

My code is:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$sql = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO user_date VALUE( '', '$name', '$date')" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
echo 'insert successful';
?>
```

I'm sure my insert is correct.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 183, accepted):

As stated in [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, `'2012-12-31'`, `'2012/12/31'`, `'2012^12^31'`, and `'2012@12@31'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYMMDD'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523'` and `'070523'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23'`, but `'071332'` is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes `'0000-00-00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05'`.

Therefore, the string `'08/25/2012'` is not a valid MySQL date literal.  You have four options (in some vague order of preference, without any further information of your requirements):

1. Configure Datepicker to provide dates in a supported format using an [`altField`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) together with its [`altFormat` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat):

   ```
   <input type="hidden" id="actualDate" name="actualDate"/>
   ```

   ```
   $( "selector" ).datepicker({
       altField : "#actualDate"
       altFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
   });
   ```

   Or, if you're happy for users to see the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, simply set the [`dateFormat` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) instead:

   ```
   $( "selector" ).datepicker({
       dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
   });
   ```
2. Use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the string:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO user_date VALUES ('', '$name', STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%m/%d/%Y'))
   ```
3. Convert the string received from jQuery into something that PHP understands as a date, such as a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object:

   ```php
   $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_POST['date']);
   ```

   and then either:

   - obtain a suitable formatted string:

     ```php
     $date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
     ```
   - obtain the UNIX timestamp:

     ```php
     $timestamp = $dt->getTimestamp();
     ```

     which is then passed directly to MySQL's [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function:

     ```sql
     INSERT INTO user_date VALUES ('', '$name', FROM_UNIXTIME($timestamp))
     ```
4. Manually manipulate the string into a valid literal:

   ```php
   $parts = explode('/', $_POST['date']);
   $date  = "$parts[2]-$parts[0]-$parts[1]";
   ```

---

### Warning

1. **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).
2. Also, as stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions:

   > This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.
3. You appear to be using either a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column for holding a date value; I recommend you consider using MySQL's `DATE` type instead.  As explained in [The `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html):

   > The `DATE` type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format. The supported range is `'1000-01-01'` to `'9999-12-31'`.
   >
   > The `DATETIME` type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays `DATETIME` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. The supported range is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` to `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`.
   >
   > The `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. `TIMESTAMP` has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` UTC to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07'` UTC.

Answer (score 10):

You should consider creating a timestamp from that date witk [mktime()](http://php.net/mktime)

eg:

```
$date = explode('/', $_POST['date']);
$time = mktime(0,0,0,$date[0],$date[1],$date[2]);
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time );
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$date_field         = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_field']));
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_date (column_name,column_name,column_name) VALUES('',$name,$date_field)") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: thanks, you give me  hint
`date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_field']));`
is works and this is exactly what I want.

Comment: Is there a way to push this higher up? It's very simple and works. The accepted answer is thorough, but doesn't appear to have this option.

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that the date format is YYYY-MM-DD on your jQuery output. I can see jQuery returns MM-DD-YYYY, which is not the valid [MySQL date format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html) and this is why it returns an error.

To convert it to the right one you could do this:

```
$dateFormated = split('/', $date);
$date = $dateFormated[2].'-'.$dateFormated[0].'-'.$dateFormated[1];
```

Then you will get formatted date that will be valid MySQL format, which is YYYY-MM-DD, i.e. *2012-08-25*

I would also recommend using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) as you insert data into database to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-and-adodb-library-general-php-website-security-with-examples/11941396#comment15907839_11941396) as a quick solution or better use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Your insert query using `mysql_real_escape_string` should rather look like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO user_date VALUE( '', '" .mysql_real_escape_string($name). "', '" .mysql_real_escape_string($date). "'" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a date object from the jquery date picker using

```
var myDate = $('element').datepicker('getDate')
```

For mysql the date needs to be in the proper format. One option which handles any timezone issues is to use moment.js

```
moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is

```
$dateArray = explode('/', $_POST['date']);
$date = $dateArray[2].'-'.$dateArray[0].'-'.$dateArray[1];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_date (column,column,column) VALUES('',$name,$date)") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pt_date" class="col-2 col-form-label">Date</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="date" value=<?php echo  date("Y-m-d") ;?> id="pt_date" name="pt_date">
</div>
```

SQL

```
$pt_date = $_POST['pt_date'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` ( `pt_date`) VALUES ( '$pt_date')";
```

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="pt_date" class="col-2 col-form-label">Date</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="date" value=<?php echo  date("Y-m-d") ;?> id="pt_date" name="pt_date">
                                        </div>

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Additionally, put all information in your answer and don't use the comment section to contain more information

Comment: No researchers should use this query -- it is insecure/unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you receive a Christmas date:
December 25, 2021 (25 de Diciembre del año 2021) in string format: "d-m-Y" for example "12-25-2021". First create a valid `DateTime` object from the received format:

```
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y","25-12-2021", new DateTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires")));
```

This generates as output:

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-12-25 10:21:11.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(30) "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
}
```

Now to get the date field from the DateTime object ready to go using *format("Y-m-d H:i:s"))*:

```
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y","25-12-2021",new DateTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

This generates as output a ready to insert value:

```
string(19) "2021-12-25 10:56:30"
```

**In summary now you can insert a formated date ('DD-MM-YYYY') in MySQL like this:**

```
<?php
//string input post like "25-12-2021"
$date_input = $_POST['date_input']; 
//create DateTime object
$date_time_obj=DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y","25-12-2021",new DateTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"));
//format date ready to insert as string at MySQL
$str_date=$date_time_obj->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
?>
```

**Now run directly from PHP to MySQL as a query:**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

//verify connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Error de conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
//prepare the query to execute
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table_example (DATE_FIELD) VALUES (?)");
//prevent sql injection
$stmt->bind_param('s', $str_date);
//execute prepared statements
$stmt->execute ();
?>
```

Comment: Why do you do `DateTime::createFromFormat("dmY", str_replace("-","","25-12-2021"), new DateTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"))` instead of `DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", "25-12-2021", new DateTimeZone("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"))`

Comment: `"INSERT INTO table_example (DATE_FIELD) VALUES ('$str_date')"` is open to SQL injections. Use parameter binding instead.

Answer (score 0):

These days, I am not good with dates. Thanks to the following work, I can print the dates in the format I want.

```php
$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$scr = strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day);
$gelis_tarihi = date('Y-m-d', $scr);

$yil = $_POST['yil'];
$ay = $_POST['ay'];
$gun = $_POST['gun'];
$birlestir = strtotime($yil . '-' . $ay . '-' . $gun);
$gelis_tarihi = date('Y-m-d', $birlestir);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try Something like this..

```
echo "The time is " . date("2:50:20");
$d=strtotime("3.00pm july 28 2014");
echo "Created date is " . date("d-m-y h:i:sa",$d);
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all store `$date=$_POST['your date field name'];`

```
insert into **Your_Table Name** values('$date',**other fields**);
```

You must contain date in single cote (' ')

I hope it is helps.