# Date field outputs during update 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with update data to database - I'm getting 0000-00-00. To the input field I'm writing data as "2010-08-10". For insert it works correctly, only for update not.

In inserting it works properly also for dates like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077071/date-is-inserting-as-0000-00-00-000000-in-mysql), for update this dates also don't work.

Above codes the both queries:

```
$rec_query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `" . $tb_best_ps . "` (id, name, date, author, www, image) VALUES ('','" . mysql_escape_string ($_POST ["name"]) . "','" . $_POST ["date"] . "','" . mysql_escape_string ($_POST ["author"]) . "','" . mysql_escape_string ($_POST ["www"]) . "','" . mysql_escape_string ($_POST ["image"]) . "')");

$query1 = mysql_query ("UPDATE `" . $tb_best_ps . "`
            SET `name` = '" . mysql_escape_string ($_POST ["name"]) . "',
            `date` = " . $_POST ["date"] . ",
            `author` = '" . mysql_escape_string ($_POST ["author"]) . "',
            `www` = '" . mysql_escape_string ($_POST ["www"]) . "',
            `image` = '" . mysql_escape_string ($_POST ["image"]) . "'
            WHERE `id` = '" . $_POST ["edit"] . "'");
```

Output when I'm using echo on update query:

```
UPDATE `swt_best_ps` SET `name` = 'Best Paper Award at ADAPTIVE 2014 for Paper XYZ', `date` = 2010-08-10, `author` = 'David Bowie', `www` = 'http://thinkmind.org/', `image` = 'http://randomweb.com/iaria2014.png' WHERE `id` = '1'
```

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: try with `date` = '" . $_POST ["date"] . "',

Answer (score 5):

You didn't quote your dates, so if you're getting something like `2014-04-08` in your $_POST value, you're actually doing

```
... date = 2014-04-08 ...
```

which will be seen as a math operation: two subtractions, and you end up doing

```
... date = 2002 ...
```

Since you haven't quoted your dates, nor escaped them, you're both inserting bad data, and vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. **ANY** external data going into a query string MUST be properly escaped and quoted.

The query building line should be

```
"`date` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']) . "'"
          ^---note the added quote                         ^---note the added quote
```

Comment: Throw a close vote in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have thought that in case of date it's acceptable without "".

Comment: no. it's impossible for mysql to know `2014-4-4` is a date, and not a double-subtraction. that's why you need the quotes - to make it a string, which mysql will then be able to figure out it's a date.