# PHP Date Function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to store the current date and time in a MySQL database, but when  storing it stores in a different format:

- I'm using `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`
- But it's stored as `20/16/1017`
- It should be `2016-10-17 15:23:23`

View

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
<input type="hidden"  name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>">
```

Model

```
function InsertAdd($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('advertisements', $data);
    }
```

Controller

```
$data = array(

                    'Date' => $this->input->post('date'),

                );
```

Note: - i have changed my type to datetime and default is currenttime in mysql db

Comment: you can only convert it in `2016-10-17 00:00:00`

Comment: SO maybe if you shared the code that actually does the storing to the database we could do something **other than guess**

Comment: It would also be useful to know the DataType of the Column you are storing this date value into!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly: dataType is Varchar i guess because value is `20/16/1017` maybe

Comment: @devpro Maybe! but that would not explain how the format got scrambled. My **guess** is OP is not actually storing `$data` but something else

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes its varchar(255).what i am doing here is simply submitting a form.im passing date as hidden value.

Comment: **Dont store datetime in VARCHAR columns**. Store them in DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatypes

Comment: debug the code so there will be you know the issue

Comment: @TimSpeckhals Read his reply to me

Comment: @colombo: Try changing your date field to this: `date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i change it to DATETIME. but now it prints 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: @colombo Have you already tried storing the timestamp (`time()`) in a `int(11)` field?

Comment: ohhhhh, now u need to store values again :)

Comment: **Show us** the PHP code that you use to store this value to the database **Edit** your question, dont paste code in a comment

Comment: Hope this help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077071/date-is-inserting-as-0000-00-00-000000-in-mysql

Comment: Is the table column called `Date` or `date`

Comment: dont know why are u using `$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` you can use TimeStamp data type and and Default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score -2):

use strtotime to replace slash with - signs. Below should work:

```
  $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date)));
```

Comment: Couldn't you just short it down to `$date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);`?

Comment: He appears to be using the current time, i.e. no second parameter. So this is irrelevant