# Jquery datepicker mysql date format

Tags: php, datepicker

I know there are some answers in this topic but i'm fresh and can't manage to do it
I have insered Jquery UI DatePicker into PHP code but when I'm sending data to MySql I get  this Error: `Incorrect date value: '' for column 'date' at row 1`

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
    })
</script>
</head>

</body>
<form action="query_insert.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<body>
```

query_insert.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "user", "pass");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="INSERT INTO expenses (date) VALUES ('$_POST[datepicker]'
?>
```

what I have to change to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You've got multiple things wrong with your html..

```
</body>
<form action="query_insert.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<body>
```

should be

```
<body>
<form action="query_insert.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker">
<input type="submit" value="INSERT DATE">
</form>
</body>
```

Basically, you have to add a `name` attribute to the `input` field for it to be included in `_POST` and `_GET` requests, you should also close the `form` (but this wont stop it from being posted)

also, your `body` tags were the wrong way around.

in your `query_insert.php` file you need to finish your INSERT statement:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO expenses (date) VALUES ('$_POST[datepicker]'
```

should be

```
$sql="INSERT INTO expenses (date) VALUES ('" . $_POST['datepicker'] . "')";
```

**Warning**: I would make sure you validate the `$_POST['datepicker']` before inserting it though

Answer (score 0):

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', (OKE)
```

php function;

$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";

input -> 2013-10-6

output -> '2013-10-6'

Mysql insert => '2013-10-6'

and we are done..

Comment: Have you even looked at the question properly to see why it's not working?

Comment: 'yyyy-mm-dd' for the full 4 digit year

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find more information:

[PHP mysql insert date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120433/php-mysql-insert-date-format)

But you can try

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO expenses (date) VALUES ( date('yyy-mm-dd','$_POST[date]'))
```