# Insert date to mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql, date

Am trying to insert date to a MYSQL column with datatype DATE . the following code is used.

```
$expiry = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $_POST['expiry']);
```

but the mysql column shows `01-Jan-70 12:00:00 AM` . have also used `strtotime()` but it seems to insert NULL.

The html input takes `YYYY-MM-DD` as date format input

any help appreciated.

Comment: That date format doesn't match MySQL native date format. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: thank you for the answer. am actually not sure. kindly tell which format to use

Comment: `DATE` uses `YYYY-MM-DD`, `DATETIME` (eg) `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, see the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Comment: good answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120433/php-mysql-insert-date-format

Comment: Could you show use the `Table information` and the `SQL Insert statement` ?

Comment: am actually adding a new parameter to a already built (long code) of php web service.

Comment: try to print $_POST and check whether it holds value for "expiry" or not

Comment: thank you. problem seems to be solved. please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the comments. although all comments may likely be helpful but Wasim's link seemed to provide the solution:

have simply saved the date in a variable without any transformations as follows:

`$expiry = $_POST['expiry'];`  // $_POST['expiry'] = YYYY-MM-DD

thank you for all the help though..