# Date to sql db fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have the below datepciker:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-YYYY'
        }).val(getTodaysDate(0)); // For current date

    });

  function getTodaysDate (val) {
    var t = new Date, day, month, year = t.getFullYear();
    if (t.getDate() < 10) {
        day = "0" + t.getDate();
    }
    else {
        day = t.getDate();
    }
    if ((t.getMonth() + 1) < 10) {
        month = "0" + (t.getMonth() + 1 - val);
    }
    else {
        month = t.getMonth() + 1 - val;
    }

    return (day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
   }
</script>
```

The input:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker">
```

And here I'm trying to insert the date to my MySQL db. There is no error message, the insert command runs OK, but the date field in my db is empty/NULL.

```
$date = $_POST['datepicker'];
$sql="INSERT INTO table (dt) VALUES ('$date')";
```

Is this some value type issue or what? The `dt` column in my db is `DATE`.

***UPDATE** @Dwza:
So I modified the script:

```
dateFormat: 'YYYY-mm-dd'
```

and

```
return (year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
```

And the `INSERT` suggested by the link you mentioned:

```
$parts = explode('-', $_POST['datepicker']);
$date  = "$parts[2]-$parts[0]-$parts[1]";
$sql="INSERT INTO transfer (dt) VALUES ('$date')";
```

Still no go.

****SOLVED:**

```
$date  = "$parts[0]-$parts[1]-$parts[2]";
```

Comment: unlike jQuery or JavaScript, `$_POST['datepicker'];` PHP catches on the basis of `name`, not `id`!! :)

Comment: I've just added `name` as well, check Daan's answer, but still the same.

Comment: What value do you get in `$_POST['datepicker']`? If it contains something that looks like a date then maybe the format is different (e.g. yyyy-mm-dd vs. mm/dd/yyy) and you'll either have to change the date picker format, or change db locale.

Comment: @Petr'PePa'Pavel I alredy mentioned that `dt` is `DATE()`. `$_POST['datepicker']` returns `11/07/2014` as expected.

Comment: check my post, you just have a format problem

Comment: an other question, what do you expact to do with the `val`in `getTodaysDate` ? i mean if you pass a 20, this will propably causes some wired output ^^

Comment: i added a update to my post. no need to explode ^^ or leave return like it was in beginning and than explode in php to sort it in the right date string format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case that you try to insert a string (date) into a column from type DATE, you need a valid date format string.

this `11/07/2014` seems to be a german date format :D

check **[this answere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120433/php-mysql-insert-date-format)**

**Quote:**

> MySQL recognizes [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, `'2012-12-31'`, `'2012/12/31'`, `'2012^12^31'`, and `'2012@12@31'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYMMDD'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523'` and `'070523'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23'`, but `'071332'` is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes `'0000-00-00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05'`.

this should solve your problem :)

change this

```
return (day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
```

to this

```
return (month + '/' + day + '/' + year);
```

or

```
return (year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
```

**EDIT for Q:**

You don't have to explode the data, its already valid date format after you change the retrun like i sayed above.

you could leave it like you have on beginning and than use explode.

Comment: I haven't realize that... So if in the script the format is set `dateFormat: 'mm-dd-YYYY'` then why it's actually `dd/mm/YYYY`?

Comment: you have `return (day + '/' + month + '/' + year);` this is german ^^

Comment: sorry I was overlooking his getTodaysDate() function call.

Comment: no problem @VMai, happens :) i realized it when he posted his output ^^

Comment: `$date  = "$parts[2]-$parts[0]-$parts[1]";` was missed. It's OK now. Thank you again.

Comment: One more interesting stuff. If the form loads the datepicker shows the current date in format `YYYY-mm-dd` like I want it, but if I pick some date from the calendar it shows up like this `mm/dd/YYYY`. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a name `datepicker` in your input field like so:

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker">
```

Comment: I thought it detects it by the `id` rather than the `name`. Anyway I've just added a `name` as well, but I still have the very same issue.