# get recent most Row specific to date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
id |value |date
-------------------
1  |2.8   |28-3-14
2  |2.9   |28-7-14
3  |3.9   |20-1-14
```

in this table i need to get the value of `21-3-14`.
but if value or object is not present for that then query get output of `20-1-14` directly without one by one search object by minus date by 1 day.
if any one know about this please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **sort by date**

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE date<='21-3-14' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Based on your table it should print:

```
2.8
```

Assuming the date 21-3-14 wasn't there, it should print:

```
3.9
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT 
        * 
FROM 
        <tablename> 
WHERE 
        STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d-%m-%y') <= STR_TO_DATE('YOUR_DATE','%d-%m-%y')
ORDER BY 
        `date` DESC < LIMIT 1 >
```

It is recommended to store date in date format i.e. < yyyy-mm-dd >

you may refer,

[PHP mysql insert date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120433/php-mysql-insert-date-format)