# How to insert TIMESTAMP into my MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

In the MySQL table I have a field called date its type is called timestamp and the default is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. However, if I leave the field blank in MySQL I get an error. When I try to insert something into it like `time()` I receive the date as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

```
<?php

    $name         = "";
    $email        = "";
    $subject      = "";
    $comments     = "";
    $nameError    = "";
    $emailError   = "";
    $subjectError = "";
    $x            = 5;
    function filterData($data)
    {
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        return $data;
    }
    $connection = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
    if (!$connection) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    
    
    $select_database = mysql_select_db("contact");
    
    if (!$select_database) {
        echo "could not select database " . mysql_error();
        
    }
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        //handles the name 
        $name = filterData($_POST["name"]);
        if (empty($name)) {
            $nameError = "please don't leave the name field blank";
        }
        //handles the email
        $email = filterData($_POST["email"]);
        if (empty($email)) {
            $emailError = "please don't leave the email field blank";
        }
        
        //handles the subject
        $subject = filterData($_POST["subject"]);
        if (empty($subject)) {
            $subjectError = "please don't leave this field blank";
        }
        
        $comments = filterData($_POST["comments"]);
        
    }
    
    $insertation = "INSERT INTO contactinfo (name, email, subject, date, comments)
        VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', '', '$comments')";
    
    $insertationQuery = mysql_query($insertation, $connection);
    
    if (!$insertationQuery) {
        echo "Could not process your information " . mysql_error();
    } else {
        echo "Thank you for submitting the information";
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: **Note:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7, use `mysqli_*` functions or PDO instead.

Comment: Please can you show your table structure here ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12120457/3101532) regarding formatting dates for MySQL

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In addition to checking your table setup to confirm that the field is set to `NOT NULL` with a default of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, you can insert date/time values from PHP by writing them in a string format compatible with MySQL.

```
 $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

This will give you the current date and time in a string format that you can insert into MySQL.

Answer (score 29):

Please try `CURRENT_TIME()` or `now()` functions

```
"INSERT INTO contactinfo (name, email, subject, date, comments)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', NOW(), '$comments')"
```

OR

```
"INSERT INTO contactinfo (name, email, subject, date, comments)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', CURRENT_TIME(), '$comments')"
```

OR you could try with PHP `date` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$insertation = "INSERT INTO contactinfo (name, email, subject, date, comments)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '$comments')";
```

You can use this Query. [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp)

Remember to use the parenthesis CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to insert the current timestamp manually as `MySQL` provides this facility to store it automatically. When the `MySQL` table is created, simply do this:

- select `TIMESTAMP` as your column type
- set the `Default` value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
- then just `insert` any rows into the table without inserting any values for the `time` column

You'll see the `current timestamp` is automatically inserted when you insert a row. Please see the attached picture. [image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have a specific integer timestamp to insert/update, you can use PHP [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function with your timestamp as second arg :

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $myTimestamp)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DEFAULT` value of a column in MySql is used only if it isn't provided a value for that column.
So if you

```
INSERT INTO contactinfo (name, email, subject, date, comments)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', '', '$comments')
```

You are not using the `DEFAULT` value for the column `date`, but you are providing an empty string, so you get an error, because you can't store an empty string in a `DATETIME` column.
The same thing apply if you use `NULL`, because again `NULL` is a value.
However, if you remove the column from the list of the column you are inserting, MySql will use the `DEFAULT` value specified for that column (or the data type default one)

Answer (score 1):

You can try on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` `function` while passing `DML` query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wiht *TIMESTAMP(curdate(), curtime())* for use the current time.