# Insert values in two rows in a SQL table at the same time

Tags: php, sql, database

This is my php file I want to insert value of the status in two row at the same time.

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $PersonID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PersonID']);
    $FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
    $Status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Status']);

    $uname = trim($uname);
    $email = trim($email);
    $upass = trim($upass);

    // email exist or not
    $query = "SELECT PersonID FROM attandance WHERE PersonID='$PersonID'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result); // if email not found then register

    if($count == 0){
        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO state(PersonID,FirstName,Status)    VALUES('$PersonID','$FirstName','$Status')"))
        { ?>
            <script>alert('successfully Added ');</script>
            <?php
        }
        else
        { ?>
            <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
            <?php
        }       
     }
     else
     {
     ?>
        <script>alert('Sorry PersonID already taken ...');</script>
        <?php
     }
 }

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"; 
echo "<html>\n"; 
echo "<head>\n"; 
echo "  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n"; 
echo "  <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n"; 
echo "  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Blank Page</title>\n";
echo "</head>\n";
echo "<body>\n";

echo "          \n"; 
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$query  = "SELECT * FROM attandance ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border=\"2\">\n"; 
echo "   <tr>\n"; 
echo "      <th>PersonId</th>\n"; 
echo "      <th>First Name</th>\n";
echo "      <th>Status</th>\n"; 


echo "    </tr>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   
    $PersonID=$row['PersonID'];
    $FirstName=$row['FirstName'];
    echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"user_id\" value=\" $PersonID\">   </td>\n"; 

    echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"full_name\" value=\" $FirstName\"></td>\n"; 
    echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"full_name\" value=\" $Status\"></td>\n"; 

    echo "</tr>\n";
}

echo " </table>\n";
echo "<input id=\"button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btn-signup\" value=\"Sign-Up\">\n";

echo "</body>\n";
echo "</html>\n";
echo "\n";
?>
```

I want to add the status of both field at once using the button. But it is not working. Can anyone help me. In the state table I want to add values to two rows at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Bad Code :) but

your read this POST

```
$PersonID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PersonID']);
$FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
$Status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Status']);
```

and this input

```
echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"user_id\" value=\" $PersonID\">   </td>\n"; 

echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"full_name\" value=\" $FirstName\"></td>\n"; 
echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"full_name\" value=\" $Status\"></td>\n";
```

change the name of the input, try this

```
echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"PersonID\" value=\" $PersonID\">   </td>\n"; 

echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"FirstName\" value=\" $FirstName\"></td>\n"; 
echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"Status\" value=\" $Status\"></td>\n";
```

and where is the form? read this: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: I changed the name even then when i click button nothing happens

Comment: you need around the input this: <form action="#" method="post"></form>

Comment: thank you, i also want to know how can we add date type from the input field in sql while creating Table

Comment: the best anwser is :) read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120433/php-mysql-insert-date-format , all what you need found here :)

Comment: when i click the button only the last row is getting updated, and in the database only the last row shows

Comment: okay you need a array of input like this: `echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"PersonID[$PersonID]\" value=\" $PersonID\">   </td>\n"; 

echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"FirstName[$PersonID]\" value=\" $FirstName\"></td>\n"; 
echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"Status[$PersonID]\" value=\" $Status\"></td>\n";`   and then you need a loop for the request! Search for a Tutorial like "input array php"