# Why getting always positive value for result on mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
$result="";
echo($uname.'</br>');
echo($pwd);
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("user_login_test",$con);
$sql="SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE username='".$uname."'";
if($result=mysql_query($sql))
{
echo($result);
echo("Extracted<br>");
}
else
{
echo("NOT Extracted");
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['password'];
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

I am doing above code for extracting values. If Username matches it show the value but if I give wrong input text it also shows "Extracted" with no value why? Please help me???

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).

Comment: Also, as stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Comment: Please read more about SQL injections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-and-adodb-library-general-php-website-security-with-examples/11941396

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the PHP manual entry for the [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, **mysql_query()** returns a [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) on success, or **`FALSE`** on error.

Your `$result` variable therefore holds a MySQL resource irrespective of whether there is a match on the `username` column: testing such a resource using `if` will always evaluate to **`TRUE`** (unless the query itself threw an error).

The manual goes on to explain:

> The returned result resource should be passed to [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.
>
> Use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to find out how many rows were returned for a SELECT statement or [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to find out how many rows were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.

In your case, you could test using `mysql_num_rows()` to determine whether any records were returned by the query (i.e. whether the `WHERE` condition was satisfied).

Comment: So how i can check if value is extracted or not?? I want to show.

Comment: @user1611964: As indicated above, you can use `if (mysql_num_rows($result)) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You have write wrong logic for extract username.
I have modify your code check it.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE username='".$uname."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql)
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
echo("Extracted<br>");
}
else
{
echo("NOT Extracted");
}
```

Comment: If you got the answer, could you please accept Harry's answer, just click the check mark (just look a little bit higher, right under voting) or read more here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/195067