# How to prevent null values to updating MySQL database

Tags: mysql, forms

My update query is

```
"UPDATE registration SET `dob` = '".$theDate."' , pwd='".$_REQUEST['n_password']."', name='".$_REQUEST['n_name']."' where id='".$_SESSION['id']."' "
```

Problem is that it is not necessary that user update all fields so if it happens there are null values coming from form and it will replace earlier value in database.

I can update it one by one after checking if field value is not null but if there is any other way r tutorial please help me

Comment: Isn't it so that you should employ all checks (both server-side and client-side) before any external data reaches your script?

Comment: This looks horrible like one big SQL injection honeypot. Oh, and probably the `php` tag is missing, I guess?

Comment: SQL Injections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-and-adodb-library-general-php-website-security-with-examples/12123649#12123649

Comment: @LLIa now i understand that what is sql injection and now start using escaping input's but still not understand PDO what it exactly, i had gone through mysql pdo tutorial but not getting much....

Answer (score 2):

> I can update it one by one after checking if field value is not null
>   but if there is any other way r tutorial please help me

Don't issue an `UPDATE` query after you check each value, instead add that column to the query you're building, then execute just one `UPDATE` with only the columns that had values.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=whatever', 'user', 'password');
$params = array();

$sql = "UPDATE REGISTRATION SET `dob` = ?";
$params[] = $theDate;

if (!empty($_REQUEST['n_password'])) {
  $sql .= ", `pwd` = ?";
  $params[] = $_REQUEST['n_password'];
}

if (!empty($_REQUEST['n_name'])) {
  $sql .= ", `name` = ?";
  $params[] = $_REQUEST['n_name'];
}

$sql .= " WHERE `id` = ?";
$params[] = $_SESSION['id'];

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: thanks a lot but i don't think that i can use PDO as i have not enough experience & knowledge and i have to finish project soon, but i will try it latter, if you have any other way then please let me know

Comment: This is the complete code to use PDO to execute your query. There is nothing else to learn.

Comment: @DanGrossman - Thanks. Just wondering why you opted for  ```!empty```  instead of ```isset```  in the if blocks ?