# Mysql error when calling stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql

I create a stored procedure, and I get an error when I call it.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''results0.79123800+1345985910.html')' at line 1

This is how I call it from my php code:

```
  mysql_query("CALL lastscan($task_id,'$file_name')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I have the sp in my database..

If it is a quote thing, how do I escape the variable I put inside, without modified the stored procedure?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: If it's a quote thing, then use prepared statements.

Comment: no need to spam such comments. I am using pdo..it is an old application that I am working on.. I dont care for now. knittl.. I cant swap between using mysql_query to mysqli/pdo..

Comment: For those who interested in SQL Injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-and-adodb-library-general-php-website-security-with-examples/12123649

Comment: It is a local application..it will never be uploaded to the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax here, use this please:

```
mysql_query("CALL lastscan('" .$task_id. "', '" .$file_name. "')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd, please approve the answer