# Why does my INSERT statement fail without error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was trying to insert a row in a table but it is not inserted without showing any error:

```
$sql="(INSERT INTO as_registration (roll, registrationid, fullname, username, 
       password, dob, courseid, email, gender, phoneno, status) 
       VALUES ('".$roll."','".$regid."','".$name."','".$username."','"
       .$pwd."','".$dob."',".intval($c_id['courseid']).",'".$email."','"
       .$gender."',".$phone.",'".$status."'))";
```

Where is the error in this statement?

Comment: I can't even read that. Is it PHP or something? Is your phone number really not a string?! I assume you're cleaning all the values to prevent SQL injection somewhere else? How are you actually doing the insert? Why are there parens around the entire statement?

Comment: Why do you concatenate all that?!

Comment: yes trying to insert through php. i have done without parens also but not inserted.

Comment: Could you post what is in $sql instead?

Comment: First, are you sure that the query is actually executed? Perhaps the code just does not run it. If it is actually executed, try writing the query in an easier-to-read way.

Comment: Did you check for mysql errors? What does it return? Add `echo $sql;`. What does it display?

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello Did formatting for you . It was kind of hard to track the string like this. It gave me headache :(

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can delete `double quotes` and '.' and '(' caracter

```
$sql="INSERT INTO as_registration (roll, registrationid, fullname, username, password, dob, courseid, email, gender, phoneno, status ) VALUES ('$roll','$regid','$name','$username','$pwd','$dob',{c_id['courseid']} ,'$email','$gender',$phone,'$status')"
```

Comment: I don't think you can call the PHP function intval() by just putting it inside the string like that...

Comment: I'am happy to help you user1611964

Comment: @user1611964 As this answer solves your problem why don't select it as the answer? That will help future users to find out the correct answer more gracefully and quickly :)

Comment: In which MySQL version is `intval` a valid function?

Comment: If this answer worked, your server must be powered by magic. `...ob',.intval($c_id['courseid']),'$em...` really?

Comment: @AghilasYakoub; remove the **.intval($c_id['courseid']).**; just use **{c_id['courseid']}** instead. It's simpler and has no error.

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't use parentheses at the beginning and at the end, try using this query please:

```
    $sql = "
INSERT INTO 
    as_registration (roll, registrationid, fullname, username, password, dob, courseid, email, gender, phoneno, status ) 
VALUES 
    ('". mysql_real_escape_string($roll) ."','". mysql_real_escape_string($regid) ."','" 
       . mysql_real_escape_string($name) ."','". mysql_real_escape_string($username) ."','"
       . mysql_real_escape_string($pwd) ."','". mysql_real_escape_string($dob) ."',"
       . mysql_real_escape_string(intval($c_id['courseid'])) .",'". mysql_real_escape_string($email) ."','"
       . mysql_real_escape_string($gender) ."','". mysql_real_escape_string($phone) ."','". mysql_real_escape_string($status) ."')";
```

If you use your code just like this then it's vulnerable for SQL Injection. I would strongly recommend using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) as you insert data into your database to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-and-adodb-library-general-php-website-security-with-examples/11941396), as a quick solution or better use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Besides if you use `mysql_*` to connect to your database, then I'd recommend reading the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions,
where they point out, that this extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, they say, you should use either the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension.

Comment: @llia Rostovtsev; your suggestion is topnotch, but the answer......not so much. There's a big chance the OP will have a hard time understanding it. And your assumption is that the OP uses **mysql_*** (which is very likely);  however, if the OP used **mysqli**, your answer will throw an error. :-D Thanks for the laugh comment.

Comment: @Sam I was bending over the limits and provided for the uncertain question quite certain answer. Asker could write few lines to me and I would rearrange my answer depending on what would be said. Thank you too! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first and last parentheses "(" and ")".

Answer (score 0):

The following code is equivalent to the code you posted.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO as_registration (roll, registrationid, fullname, username, password, dob, courseid, email, gender, phoneno, status )
      VALUES ('$roll', '$regid', '$name', '$username', '$pwd', '$dob', ".intval($c_id['courseid']).", '$email', '$gender', $phone, '$status')";
```

[Documentation about double-quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
$courceid = intval($c_id['courseid']);
$sql="(INSERT INTO as_registration
(roll, registrationid, fullname, username, password, dob, courseid, email, gender, phoneno, status )
VALUES
('$roll','$regid','$name','$username','$pwd','$dob','$courceid','$email','$gender','$phone','$status'))";
```

Comment: Alfred, interesting idea about taking `intval` out of the query but what makes you think it's the case? :) I have never encounter such problem, have you? Just out of the curiosity?