# Syntax error, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" with the following code:

```
$field_sql = 'SHOW FIELDS FROM '.$dbtable.' WHERE FIELD = '.$field;
$field_q = mysql_query($field_sql,$MJCONN);
$field_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($field_q);
}while($field_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($field_q));
```

I think it has to do with brackets but I have not been able to solve the problem, any help would be very welcome.

Comment: Echo out your query and run it against the database. Your query isn't working for some reason.

Comment: That means your query failed. You can use `mysql_error()` to find out why.

Comment: You should probably also look at moving to `PDO` or `mysqli_*`, as `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated.

Comment: @user1658413: Please read my recent post about SQL injections, you could find it interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-and-adodb-library-general-php-website-security-with-examples

Comment: `mysql_query($field_sql,$MJCONN);` returned `FALSE` - check why!

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query` returns `false` on failure of the query. I like to use this instead of `mysql_query`:

```
function mysql_query2($sql,$conn=null) {
    $r = $conn ? mysql_query($sql,$conn) : mysql_query($sql);
    if( $e = mysql_error()) trigger_error("MySQL error: ".$e,E_USER_WARNING);
    return $r;
}
```

This performs the query, then checks for errors and makes them PHP warnings. This way, you can easily see if the query fails.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it myself, it was a question of missing characters, in this case quotes.

Solution:

```
$field_sql = 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `' . $table . '` WHERE FIELD = "' . $column . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$field_q` is `FALSE`, because your query failed. See [documentation](http://se.php.net/msql_query).
Fix your query to get rid of the issue :)