# why cant i insert data into my sql db with php

Tags: php, mysql

its rather frustrating and im sure its an easy fix. as far as i can tell my code is spot on which leads me to believe there is a server problem. i have created the DB and i can insert data into table from the command line. if it helps i am using WAMP.

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="permission"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="login"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 
$myfname=$_POST['fname'];
$mylname=$_POST['lname'];
$myemail=$_POST['email'];



// To protect MySQL injection 
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// username taken
echo "Username already taken";
exit();
}

//protection against sql injection
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
$value = is_array($value) ?
array_map(stripslashes_deep, $value) :
stripslashes($value) ;
return $value;
}
$_POST = array_map(stripslashes_deep, $_POST);
$_GET = array_map(stripslashes_deep, $_GET);
$_COOKIE = array_map(stripslashes_deep, $_COOKIE);
$_REQUEST = array_map(stripslashes_deep, $_REQUEST);
}

//insert form into DB members




'INSERT INTO members SET
username="' . $myusername . '",
password="' . $mypassword . '",
email="' . $myemail . '",
fname="' . $myfname . '",
lname="' . $mylname . '",';

session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:registersuccess.html");
?>
```

Comment: Part of the problem might be that you're not obviously [escaping any of your SQL variables](http://bobby-tables.com/php) so any data with irregular characters like `"` will cause this query to explode and/or trash your entire database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the SQL injection issue, you have an unnecessary trailing comma.

Change:

```
lname="' . $mylname . '",';
```

to:

```
lname="' . $mylname . '"';
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the case, I'm sure. +1. @user1669503 Read more about SQL injections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-and-adodb-library-general-php-website-security-with-examples  or at least use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: although im sure this was an issue, it appears to have not changed anything

Answer (score 1):

It might because you have an extra trailing comma :
`lname="' . $mylname . '",';` should probably be `lname="' . $mylname.'"';`

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you don't know how to do a query, it's like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Create table doesn't return a resultset */
if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {
    printf("Table myCity successfully created.\n");
}
```

Ref.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php