# Deleting directory

Tags: php, directory, delete-file

I have a problem when my uploads folder has been deleted after I delete directory in that uploads folder with this code below

```
function delete_files($target,$target_thumb) {

if(is_dir($target)){
    $files = glob( $target . '*', GLOB_MARK ); 

    foreach( $files as $file )
    {
        delete_files( $file );      
    }

    rmdir( $target );
} elseif(is_file($target)) {
    unlink( $target );  
}

 if(is_dir($target_thumb)){
    $files = glob( $target_thumb . '*', GLOB_MARK ); 

    foreach( $files as $file )
    {
        delete_files( $file );      
    }

    rmdir( $target_thumb );
} elseif(is_file($target_thumb)) {
    unlink( $target_thumb );  
}
}
```

All I want to do is to delete category and files in it from uploads folder.. What it does, it deletes all uploads folder with all files in it.. Have no idea why. Any suggestions would be helpful.

**EDIT 1:**

I see.. `$target` shows as  `"../uploads/"` after I echo it..

```
$cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
$cat_data = data_cat($cat_id,'name');

if (empty($cat_id)){
header("Location: categories.php");
exit;
}

if (isset($_GET['cat_id'])){
$cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];

$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cattegories WHERE cat_id = $cat_id");

$target = ('../uploads/'.$cat_data['name']);
$target_thumb = ('../uploads/thumbs/'.$cat_data['name']);
delete_cat($cat_id);
delete_files($target,$target_thumb);
header("Location: categories.php");
exit();
}
```

It seems that my function cant grab the name of the category..

**EDIT 2:**

Thats my `data_cat` function:

```
function data_cat($cat_id){
    $cat_id = (int)$cat_id;

    $args = func_get_args();
    unset($args[0]);
    $fields = '`'.implode('`,`', $args).'`';

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `cattegories` WHERE `cat_id` = $cat_id");
    $query_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    foreach ($args as $field){
        $args[$field] = $query_result[$field];
    }
    return $args;

}
```

P.S. Name cattegories is correct, I just made a mistake in db naming it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have `rmdir( $target );` and `rmdir( $target_thumb );` in your script. Get rid of it and you will have your directories left as you want.

PHP Manual: [`rmdir`](https://www.php.net/rmdir)  — removes directory

> Attempts to remove the directory named by dirname. The directory must
> be empty, and the relevant permissions must permit this. A E_WARNING
> level error will be generated on failure.

###EDIT 1:

According you your last comment, you should debug your `$target` and `$target_thumb` variables:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $target );
echo '</pre>';
```

What is the output for that? Make an edit to you question and provide the output and I will be able to help you out.

###EDIT 2:

After looking at your posted code, I would strongly suggest to restructure it, as it's vulnurable to SQL injections: [SQL injections in ADOdb and general website security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-in-adodb-and-general-website-security)

Comment: You misunderstood me.. I want them to delete.. When I remove category from my website I want these folders with the name of that category be removed from uploads folder..

Comment: Lets say I have 1 category named "Glass", category is created in uploads/glass and uploads/thumbs/glass and that name is inserted in db.. When I want to delete this category named Glass I want to delete it from db, which is doing ok and then remove folder from uploads/ and uploads/thumbs and thats where all uploads folder is deleting for no reason..

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees What is `data_cat` function look like?

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees At last what is the *URL* parametrs `.php?cat_id=`... Provide an example.

Comment: Ok it works..My stuuuupid mistake, I misspelled my db name on that data_cat func.. Thanks Ilia Rostovtsev for pointing to the right direction!!

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees You are welcome. I also wanted to point out that you pass `'name'` in `data_cat($cat_id,'name');` and inside of `data_cat` function you don't process it at all.

Comment: Well i do, as this fields 'name' acts as a $fields in that function and selects only what you call in data_cat, in this case its a name, so it select $fields as a 'name' from db and returns it..if thats what you meant.